# Improve performance finding matches in a big list/array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, performance

I am building a tool to find images in a big folder of images (400k images). On that folder I have images like this:

c:\images\100001_01.jpg
c:\images\100001_05.jpg
c:\images\100001_07.jpg
c:\images\100005_05.jpg
c:\images\100010_00.jpg

Then I have my references in a text box, but only the 6 digit number:
100001
100005
100006
Etc

So I have let's say 1000 references I need to have the images for, I want to loop through all the image folder and take the file if exists. I have built this using both an array with loops and a list and getting the index. I thought getting the index of the list would be much faster, but they are actually the same.

Here are the two routines I have developed, one is using a list and then getting FindIndex to get the index. The second option is looping through all the references and at the same time looping through all images to check if any contains that reference - that is 400 million loops if I use a set of 1000 references!

Using a list takes 69 seconds, however looping through the arrays takes 64 seconds. Nevertheless taking all images on the directory using GetFile takes 120 seconds already.

Can you think of any way to make this faster?

```
 Private Sub ExtractImagesUsingList()

    Dim ListOfReferences As New List(Of String) 'the actual list of references is in a textbox, ie.: 100001, 100002, etc

    For Each line In txtBox.Lines
        ListOfReferences.Add(line.ToString)
    Next

    Dim ListOfimages As New List(Of String)

    For Each file In IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\images\")
        ListOfimages.Add(file)
    Next

    For Each ref In ListOfReferences
        Dim index As Integer = ListOfimages.FindIndex(Function(x As String) x.Contains(ref))
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ExtractImagesUsingArrayLoop()

    Dim ListOfreferences As New List(Of String)'the actual list of references is in a textbox

    For Each line In txtBox.Lines
        If line.Length > 1 Then
            ListOfReferences.Add(line.ToString)
        End If
    Next

    Dim ArrayImages() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles("c:\images\")

    For Each reference In ListOfReferences
        For Each image In ArrayImages
            If image.Contains(reference) Then
                 Exit For ' I exist the FOR here because I am only interested in one image per reference
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: When you say 'references' you're referring to the 6-digit numeric code that could be a prefix for one or multiple images correct?  Also, is the goal to return the list of image file paths associated with that code as quickly as possible?

Comment: @ParrishHusband yes, the references are always a 6 digit code but the images always have _xx, it is not consistent so I have to find the path that matches the reference and they I would take that path to copy the image to a separate folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to accomplish, but you could improve performance by implementing `Directory.EnumerateFiles`.

Additionally, you could pair this with the built-in search function using a wildcard match against the known reference key from the reference list.

Finally, if the image directory is not subject to frequent changes, you could cache the images in a dictionary to speed up future searches.

Here is a rough example of those ideas.  Note I've removed any references to form controls, and assume parameters are instead being passed in.

```
Private _imageMap As Dictionary(Of String, ICollection(Of String))

Public ReadOnly Property ImageMap As Dictionary(Of String, ICollection(Of String))
    Get
        If _imageMap Is Nothing Then
            _imageMap = New Dictionary(Of String, ICollection(Of String))()
        End If

        Return _imageMap
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub RefreshImageMap()
    _imageMap = Nothing
End Sub

Public Function GetImagePaths(imageFolder As String, referenceKey As String) As ICollection(Of String)

    Dim imagePaths As ICollection(Of String) = Nothing
    If Not ImageMap.TryGetValue(referenceKey, imagePaths) Then

        imagePaths = Directory.EnumerateFiles(imageFolder, $"{referenceKey}_*.jpg").ToList()
        ImageMap.Add(referenceKey, imagePaths)

    End If

    Return imagePaths

End Function
```

Also if you wanted to run multiple reference keys through a function, but also needed to keep the original reference key passed in, you could add something like this:

```
Public Iterator Function GetImagePaths(imageFolder As String, referenceKeys As IEnumerable(Of String)) As IEnumerable(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, ICollection(Of String)))

    For Each referenceKey As String In referenceKeys

        Dim imagePaths = GetImagePaths(imageFolder, referenceKey)
        Yield New KeyValuePair(Of String, ICollection(Of String))(referenceKey, imagePaths)
    Next

End Function
```

None of this is tested, and this lacks proper parameter checks on functions, but it should give you a direction to try.

Comment: thank you, I found the Directory.EnumerateFiles and implemented it like this:

            `Dim ListOfreferences As New List(Of String)

        For Each line In txtBox.Lines
            If line.Length > 1 Then
                ListOfreferences.Add(line.ToString)
            End If
        Next

        For Each reference In ListOfreferences
            Dim imgFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\images\", reference & "*.jpg")
        Next`

I will try to implement the other part of your code but so far I got it working with a  **a 1500% performance improvement!**